# How to change Bluetooth device class on an Android phone?

Tags: android, bluetooth

Is it possible to make an Android phone present itself as not being from the Phone device class when connecting over Bluetooth?  For example, imagine I wanted to pretend my phone was a Bluetooth keyboard to another device.

I've been looking around the [Bluetooth API](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/bluetooth/package-summary.html) and I don't see anyway to change it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

COD(Class of device) cannot be changed from the application. For bluez stack in phone, COD is defined in adapter.c . Though if u want that ur phone can act as a keyboard to some other device, may be adding SDP record can help. If peer device searches for the services supported on your phone, it can recognize as HID device with the SDP record

Comment: Aw, that sucks.  I was hoping I could make my phone act as a keyboard for my PS3 or Apple TV so I didn't have to use the crappy screen keyboard.